# Dynamics CRM 2013 : I need a dynamic message on the out of the box workflow depending on the trigger

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an out of the box workflow which is triggered before delete of an **email** and cancels the workflow with a message if certain conditions are not met.

The entity is also part of another entity (**case**) using the regarding relationship.
I would want to present a dynamic message on the workflow so that I could show **distinct messages** for case deletion and email deletion.

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't have this kind of information available, you have to implement a `CodeActivity` which analyzes the execution context.

You could also skim the issue by phrasign the message to work in both cases (in my experience, users are often familiar with this kind of warning):

> The email 'Re: my awesome mail' could not be deleted because reasons. If you are seeing this message when attempting to delete a Case, foo the bar first."